# Can the AMD Radeon Graphics on the Ryzen 5 5600H drive 3 displays?

Tags: integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen

I just bought this laptop [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09T5QWMD8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09T5QWMD8)

I want to know if i can connect 2 displays in windows 10 "Extend" mode via the usbc 3.2 gen 2 of the laptop.

With that I will have 3 displays in extends mode running on the Integrated graphics. One is the integrated laptop display and 2 additionals connected by usb.

Its bad that amd specs page doesn't give you this information. I can't seem to find any authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the article
[Which AMD Radeon Video Cards Support 3 Monitors](https://www.urtech.ca/2014/03/sovled-which-amd-radeon-video-cards-support-3-monitors/),
the ATI Radeon HD 5600 Series can support up to 3 displays.

Some more information is given in the post
[AMD 5600G - how many displays does it support?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/pci9lx/amd_5600g_how_many_displays_does_it_support/)
It's a similar model, but for a comparison see
[AMD Ryzen 5 5600G vs AMD Ryzen 5 5600H](https://versus.com/en/amd-ryzen-5-5600g-vs-amd-ryzen-5-5600h).

The excellent answer by user chithanh says :

> - Maximum total resolution of all connected displays is 16384x16384, which is enough for three 5K monitors in horizontal arrangement.
> - Socket AM4 routes 3 display outputs so you can connect 3 displays to AM4 mobos directly.
> - 5600G has 4 display controllers, so with the help of DisplayPort MST hubs or daisy-chaining you can connect 4 independent displays.
> - Be aware of bandwidth requirements when using MST hubs: The MST hub needs to support DisplayPort 1.3 in order to connect two 4K@60 Hz
>   monitors.
> - You can in principle connect a 4K@60 Hz monitor via DVI and DVI->HDMI adapter, but for that you need to mod the Windows driver
>   (using pixel clock patcher), or use Linux. If you are not willing to
>   do that, buy a mobo that can connect 3 monitors via DisplayPort or
>   HDMI outputs (such as Gigabyte A520I AC).

Comment: G is a desktop processor with integrated graphics, H is a laptop processor

Comment: It all depends on the number of video ports of your computer. If you have even one DisplayPort and the monitors support daisy-chain then there is no problem. Otherwise, you could get a dock with enough video ports.

Comment: that is not the case I can have 3 hubs, each with hdmi and display port, doesn't mean the CPU/GPU will be able to drive 7 displays...

Comment: 7 displays ? Your question specified 3. Anyway, as in my answer, for the 5600 Series it's 3 displays maximum.

Comment: correct, then we are discussing how many displays. Can it drive 2 or 3 or more? If it can't drive 7 means there is a limit. And it may be more than 2 or up to only 2, anyway. you get the point

Comment: the radeon 5600 is a discrete GPU, not the same as the integrated one

Comment: It's up to 3 displays.